# C# Smart way to include images into Excel file

Tags: c#, image, export-to-excel

I'm looking for a smart way to include images into an Excel file with Office.Interop.Excel.
Basically I want to build a report, and one of my column contains images.

I am facing two problems: first I didn't find anyway to add images unless saving temporary copy into HD (my images are coming from a byte array stored in a DB), and then I can't add the picture itself into a cell, I have to compute the exact place on my WorkSheet which is not really  efficient.

Here is my code

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ByteArrayImage))
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    image.Save(directory + "\\Excel\\Temp\\image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(directory + "\\Excel\\Temp\\image.png",
                 MsoTriState.msoFalse,MsoTriState.msoTrue,580, cumulHeight, 
                 image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
    cumulHeight += image.Size.Height + 10;
    SetRowHeight(xlWorkSheet, i + 2, image.Size.Height + 10);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same problem a few weeks before. I solved the problem by binding the image to a gridview.The only downside is the image will have the name of the column of the gridview on the top left corner.If you want i can provide you the code for that.Although for my technique you wouldn't need office.interop.excel.